# c# sql database express

Tags: c#, sql, database

Im trying to insert data into a database table, the problem is that my column name (Recent Activity) has a space and its causing a problem.

```
            sql_Query = "INSERT INTO [SprinklerHistory] (";
            sql_Query += "[Recent Activity], Date, Time)";
            sql_Query += "VALUES (";
            sql_Query += "@Recent Activity, @Date, @Time)";
```

Comment: What is a '@Recent Activity' ?

Comment: MMMM, the parameter cannot have spaces either, and setting the column as [dbo].[Recent Activity] should work. i think the deal is with the param

Comment: @Remus: all that and 0 votes also. Unimpressed.

Comment: Recent Activity, Date, Time are my column names

Comment: It would appear you have not upvoted or accepted a single answer. Could you explain why you think anyone should help you?

Answer (score 2):

When passing parameter you don't need to have them directly matchup to the field names. A larger code snippet would assist but the following should work. Also try and avoid naming fields with potentially reserved words such as Date and Time.

```
sql_Query = "INSERT INTO [SprinklerHistory] ("; 
sql_Query += "[Recent Activity], [Date], [Time])"; 
sql_Query += "VALUES ("; 
sql_Query += "@RecentActivity, @Date, @Time)";
```